# How to get applescript to compare application version against a Variable

Tags: applescript

I have a line in my applescript that will not read a variable set for the name of an Application

```
set ReadAppVersion to value of version of application TheApp
```

but if I use this below it works.

```
set ReadAppVersion to value of version of application "OsiriX"
```

For some reason, I cannot read the version of the application if I have it as a variable name.

But if I use this below it works.

```
set ReadAppVersion to value of version of application "OsiriX"
```

```
on AppOsirixChecks(TheApp)
  delay 1
  tell application "Finder"
    close every window
  end tell
  do shell script "defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles FALSE"
  tell application "Dock"
    tell application "System Events"
      tell process "Dock"
        click UI element "Finder" of list 1
      end tell
    end tell
  end tell
  menu_click({"Finder", "Go", "Applications"})
  delay 1
  set ReadAppName to 0
  set ReadAppVersion to 0
  set TheRow to 2
  tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Finder"
      repeat until ReadAppName is equal to TheApp
        set ReadAppVersion to value of version of application "osirix"
        set ReadAppName to value of text field 1 of UI element 1 of row TheRow of outline 1 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of splitter group 1 of window "Applications"
        set TheRow to TheRow + 1
        if ReadAppVersion doesn't equal AppVersionOsiriX then
          log "TEST FAILURE !: The current version is: " & ReadAppVersion
        end if
      end repeat
    end tell
  end tell
  log ">>>                 Current Application Name is: " & ReadAppName
  log ">>>              Current Application version is: " & ReadAppVersion
  --return TheRow  -- this line does not seem necessary
  tell application "Finder"
    activate
    delay 2
    close every window
    do shell script "defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE"
  end tell
end AppOsirixChecks
```

> `<filepath>/upgrade_test_validation_checklist.scpt:10612:10617: execution error: OsiriX got an error: Can’t make «class valL» of version into type specifier. (-1700)`

Answer (score 1):

There is no `value of version`.

To get the `version` of an application omit `value of`

```
set ReadAppVersion to version of application "OsiriX"
```

and move the line to before the `System Events` tell block as you need to get the value only once.

Honestly I have no idea what the script is supposed to do. Why do you GUI script a `Finder` window ?

Answer (score 0):

Try asking it by it's name instead of it's reference. This works for me (without even being in a tell "Finder" block).

```
set theApplication to "EasyFind"
set theVersion to version of application named theApplication
```